# How we can implement add to any(Social networking) in MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can we implement Add to any social network widget to share photos in facebook,twitter etc in Mobilefirst platform.
I have tried the plugin from http://www.addthis.com/ 
It is working on Preview in Common Resources but failing in Android and windows 8 simulators and devices.

Can anyone suggest any other plugin for MobileFirst Platform?
Tried jquery share also by the following code but not working.

```
$('#mydiv').share({
        networks: ['facebook','pinterest','googleplus','twitter','linkedin','tumblr','in1','email','stumbleupon','digg']
    });

 <div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Explain what you want this to accomplish for your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: see this blog post for more information: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

The mentioned "plug-in" does not seem fitting for mobile apps IMO.
You can google for Cordova social sharing plug-ins instead.

One promising such plug-in for Android, iOS and Windows Phone is the [PhoneGap Social Sharing plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin).

**Note:** You cannot use the Cordova CLI installation steps to install the plug-in in Worklight/MobileFirst Platform. Instead, you need to follow the manual instructions that are provided.

Before doing so it would be prudent to read the [MFP tutorial for working with Cordova plug-ins](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/) so you will understand how it works in MFP.

---

I got it to work on iOS with some extra tweaks.

**Note:**

- Step 2 is required for Android and Windows Phone 8 as well in their respective environment
- Step 2 will need to be repeated after every build in MobileFirst Studio, because this file gets over-written on every build.

Steps:

1. There are two missing frameworks:

   - MessageUI.framework
   - Social.framework
2. Updating (in Xcode) www\worklight\cordova_plugins.js with an extra section

   ```
    {
        "file": "../js/SocialSharing.js",
        "id": "nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing",
        "clobbers": [
            "window.plugins.socialsharing"
        ]
    }
   ```

   **Note:** SocialSharing.js should be placed in common\js as well as be referenced to in the HEAD element in index.html
3. Edit SocialSharing.js by wrapping the entire contents with

   ```
   cordova.define("nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing", function(require, exports, module) {
       // file contents
   );
   ```
4. In your HTML, choose whichever sharing option you'd like from the available ones (see plug-in documentation for those).

End result:

[image]