# xcodebuild exited with code 65 :EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, socialshare

I am trying to add socialSharing to my IBM mobileFirst hybrid app..  Added the 'socialsharing.h','socialsharing.m' file but I get an error doing the Xcodebuild (cli)

The error is:

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/Pre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RandstadJobs-awbivrwbculwbcbkdgifcfkukrfk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RandstadMobileRandstadRecruiterIphone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RandstadJobs.build/Distribution-iphoneos/RandstadMobileRandstadRecruiterIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SocialSharing.o Classes/SocialSharing.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
xcodebuild exited with code: 65
[17:23:39] 'build-iphone-no-deps' errored after 14 s
[17:23:39] RunCommandError: xcodebuild did not complete [code, signal]: 65,
    at _doneHandler (/Users/Pre/Documents/Development/mymobile/dev/Recruiter/build/node_modules/build-common/tasks.js:319:19)
    at ChildProcess. (/Users/Prem/Documents/Development/mymobile/dev/Recruiter/build/node_modules/build-common/tasks.js:300:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
[17:23:39] 'build-apps' errored after 42 s
[17:23:39] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(build-iphone-no-deps)'
Message:
    build-iphone-no-deps callback

I am using Xcode v7.3 and IBM mobile first 7.1
Can you please provide some hints on how to fix this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can MobileFirst-related instructions here: [How we can implement add to any(Social networking) in MobileFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564069/how-we-can-implement-add-to-anysocial-networking-in-mobilefirst)

Xcode-wise make sure you did not forget to add the following frameworks:

- MessageUI.framework
- Social.framework

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your derived data.